# Add two insert queries to the one row php

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to add to insert queries to the one row? When I run the queries as two they both add to different rows.

```
$query1  = "INSERT INTO `mysaved` (`Username`) VALUES ('bob123')";
$query2 = "INSERT INTO `mysaved` (`Name`, `Image`) 
SELECT * 
FROM sport b
JOIN sport a
on a.Tag = b.Name
where a.SportID <> b.sportID and a.Name = 'Football'"
```

Comment: Does your second query even work? Selecting `*` from 2 tables is likely to lead to 1. errors and 2. more columns than just 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the value into the `select`.

```
INSERT INTO mysaved (Name, Image, Username)
SELECT name, image, 'bob123'
FROM sport b
JOIN sport a
on a.Tag = b.Name
where a.SportID <> b.sportID
and a.Name = 'Football'
```

Comment: The value is in the select as a static value. What do you mean? `'bob123'` would be the username from the PHP.

Comment: in my php its $username which is the logged in user

Comment: `I'm told its invalid`? Who told you that? What's invalid about it? Can you show your usage?

Comment: the user details are also in a users table

Comment: i have it set that if the query does sort it comes up as invalid query

Comment: I'm told that Name is ambiguous

Comment: Okay, that is per your DB scheme which you didn't provide. Add the table name to the column that you want to select. `SELECT b.name,` or `SELECT a.name,` depending on which table's value you want.